# Detect Click on Table Row from Generated Table with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to detect a click on the table rows, but I'm having problems. The table is generated from a javascript file and is placed inside a div inside the html.This div is named 'tableOutput'. My jquery click function will work if I set it to 'tableOutput', but I set it to '#myTable', or '#myTable tr' it will not do anything. Any advice? Thanks!

Code that generates the table:

```
function loadUsers() {
$.getJSON("api/users", function(data) {
    var userTable = "\
        <table id=\"mt\" class=\"table table-hover\"><tr><th>User ID</th><th>User Name</th><th>Password</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>DOB</th><th>Enabled</th></tr>";
    var count = 1;
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        userTable = userTable + "<tr id=\"tr" + count + "\"><td>" + value["userID"] + "</td><td>" + value["userName"] + "</td><td>" + value["password"] + "</td><td>" + value["firstName"] + "</td><td>" + value["lastName"] + "</td><td>" + value["email"] + "</td><td>" + value["phone"] + "</td><td>" + value["dateOfBirth"] + "</td><td>" + value["enabled"] + "</td></tr>";
        count = count + 1;
    });
    userTable = userTable + "</table>";
    $("#tableOutput").html(userTable);
}
);
}
```

Code that detects the click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#dp1').datepicker();
loadUsers();

$('#mt tr').on("click", function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
});
```

Comment: I think your table isnt there by the time that you bind the clicks, as getJSON is psudo-async

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind event to dynamically added elements. Since you have static parent of the table the div with id `tableOutput` you can delegate event to it.

```
$('#tableOutput').on("click", '#myTable tr', function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**Delegated events**

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't believe it was such an easy fix.