# Javascript table row click doesn't work after partial view gets refreshed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple page that displays a table of items in a partial view.

```
<div id="divList">
    @Html.Action("_list")
</div>
```

_list.cshtml displays a list of items:

```
<table id=tblList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>List</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
            <td>ItemName1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
            <td>ItemName2</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the main page, I have the following javascript so that I can get the ID of the selected row:

```
$('#tblList tr').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

The above code works but it doesn't work after the partial view gets refreshed. So I did some research and figured that I need something like:

```
$('#tblList').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    alert("row clicked");
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

But I've tried many ways and combinations and I can't get it to work.. What am I missing?
I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619012/detect-click-on-table-row-from-generated-table-with-jquery) but it didn't work either.

```
$('document').on('click', '#tblList tr', function () {
    alert("row clicked");
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are updating the content of the div with id "divList" after you wire up the click event handler. So the dynamically injected DOM elements ( the new content of that div) will not have the click event handler registered.

Register your click event using jQuery `on` on the container div.

```
$('#divList').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    alert("row clicked");
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

jQuery `on` works for current and future(dynamically injected to DOM) elements

Here is working [jsbin sample](http://jsbin.com/wanidaxaxi/edit?html,js,output).

You should not have more than one element with the same id value. Id's should be unique.

Comment: Thank you, it totally makes sense and I tried it but it's not working ...

Comment: See the updated answer. You need to make sure you do not have duplicate ids

Comment: Sorry ! I missed that. But the code i posted should work as long as you do not have any script errors in the page. See working sample here http://jsbin.com/wanidaxaxi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: hmmm it does work in your example.. It really helps to know that this should work as I wasn't sure what I was doing wrong. I'll try more. Thank you!

Comment: do you have any other script errors in the page which is preventing this  code to execute ?

Comment: I have `$('#divList').on('click', 'tr', function(){alert("clicked");});` and looks like I'm getting `TypeError: $(...).on is not a function`

Comment: Make sure you have jQuery loaded to the page before you execute this script. You may wrap this page level script inside `@section Scripts` block to ensure that your code is executed after jQuery is loaded. Take a look at [where should i place the js script files in a mvc application so jquery works well?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147155/where-should-i-place-the-js-script-files-in-a-mvc-application-so-jquery-works-we/34147263#34147263)

Comment: Ahh I see. I had added a plugin and its js file was messing up something. I removed it and now it's doing exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the click functions are already wired up to listen for clicks, but then when the partial gets refreshed, the functions don't know that they are supposed to listen to the "new" elements in the partial. Your best bet is to move the function to within the partial. That way the function also gets wired up to the latest content each time it's refreshed.